# Perl: grep is matching when it should not

Tags: regex, perl

```
sub process_ignore{
    my $col_ref = shift;
    my $ignore_ref = shift;
    foreach ( @{$ignore_ref} ) {
        if ( grep( /^$_$/, @{$col_ref})) {
            print "Will ignore column: $_\n" if $debug;     
        } else {
            print "Will not ignore column: $_\n because not a valid column" if $debug;
        }
    }

    if ($debug) {
        foreach my $val ( @{$col_ref} ) {
            print "$val\n";
        }
    }
}

&process_ignore(\@cols, \@ignores)
```

--
@cols have A_ID, STATUS, STIME
@ignores have a_id, sdd

OUTPUT:
Will ignore column: a_id
Will ignore column: sdd
A_ID
STATUS
STIME

I m not sure why its going into the the matching if block when it should not.
There is no sdd in @cols

Also, does grep ignore case? i.e a_id vs A_ID?

Comment: Where did you learn to call subroutines with `&`. That's not a good idea. It's better to call them without - `process_ignore(\@cols, \@ignores)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

`foreach ( @{$ignore_ref} ) {
        if ( grep( /^$_$/, @{$col_ref})) {`

to(at least):

`foreach my $ignore ( @{$ignore_ref} ) {
        if ( grep( /^$ignore$/, @{$col_ref})) {`

or even(if regexp not necessary):

`foreach my $ignore ( @{$ignore_ref} ) {
        if ( grep {$_ eq $ignore} @{$col_ref} ) {`

Comment: this worked. but both $_ and $ignore have the same value. why $ignore works and not $_?

Comment: grep overwrites $_. Try grep {print $_} (1,2,3) for example.

Comment: ah gotcha. I can actually do /^$ignore$/i  to make it case insentive to match a_id with A_ID where eq approach wouldnt do that.

Answer (score 1):

You're matching elements of `$col_ref` to themselves as grep temporarily trumps value of `$_`

```
    if ( grep( /^$_$/, @{$col_ref})) {
```

You can make this function more efficient by introducing look up hash,

```
sub process_ignore{
    my $col_ref = shift;
    my $ignore_ref = shift;

    my %seen;
    @seen{ @$ignore_ref } = ();
    foreach ( @$col_ref ) {
        if (exists $seen{$_}) {
            print "Will ignore column: $_\n" if $debug;     
        } else {
            print "Will not ignore column: $_\n because not a valid column" if $debug;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry. i already had it as &process_ignore(\@cols, \@ignores); i removed & but its still matching